# Exception in thread "main" cascading.flow.FlowException: unhandled exception

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

When I execute my code in eclipse maven environment, I am getting this error, as I am new to java don't know how to proceed further, any solution please.

```
Exception in thread "main" cascading.flow.FlowException: unhandled exception
    at cascading.flow.BaseFlow.complete(BaseFlow.java:954)
    at com.bitwiseglobal.engine.integration.BHSRuntime.execute(BHSRuntime.java:170)
    at com.bitwiseglobal.bhse.utilities.BHSExecution.execute(BHSExecution.java:50)
    at com.bitwiseglobal.bhse.utilities.BHSExecution.main(BHSExecution.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.planner.HadoopFlowStepJob.internalNonBlockingStart(HadoopFlowStepJob.java:100)
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.blockOnJob(FlowStepJob.java:248)
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.start(FlowStepJob.java:172)
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.call(FlowStepJob.java:134)
    at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.call(FlowStepJob.java:45)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Either this error due to cascading issue or due to java null pointer exception. If any details needed please let me know.

Comment: This error *is* due to the NullPointerException, but the fact that that's buried in the guts of Hadoop is going to make it harder to work out hat's wrong. I suspect it's a bad or missing configuration somewhere...

Comment: Configuration means you are mentioning xml configuration? or setup configuration?

Comment: I've no idea, not having used Hadoop or this cascading package you're using... but it appears to be trying to start a process, but not specifying which process to start, which sounds like a configuration issue *somewhere*.

Comment: Hi Sibikrish , can  you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606807/how-can-i-submit-a-cascading-job-to-a-remote-yarn-cluster-from-java. If you are using different jars ( some are hadoop 1.x and others hadoop 2.x), this error may come